# How can I make my new window appear silently when I am already typing in some chat window

Tags: c#, winforms, wcf

I am developing Instant Messaging application using C# Winforms. This application uses WCF service to send and Receive messages and files across the clients. this application allows me to chat Publicly, Privately and in a Group with available users.

My problem is if I am typing any message in any of the chat window; and if I receive message in another window. Focus shift to the new window and whatever I am typing it will type inn new window where I had received the message.

How can I make my new window appear silently when I am already typing in some chat window?

Comment: Please post the code for how you display the window.

Comment: I Got solution to my problem :

Answer (score 0):

I am using three diff winforms for private, public and group chat. I have a list of users to do private chat and list of groups to do group chat also i have option to do public chat with all online users. for private and group chat it creates multiple instance of respective forms.

also when i receive the message it will check if instance for particular private/group/public chat window is running or not if it is running it will use existing instance to display messages else it will create new instance for respective chat window.

I have got solution to my problem :

I am finding ActiveControl and ActiveForm 
and then I am using below code to set my active window

if (_ActiveControl != null)
                            {

```
                            if (_ActiveControl is Form)
                            {
                                if ((_ActiveControl is {form name for public chat window}) || (_ActiveControl is {form name for private chat window}) || (_ActiveControl is {form name for Group chat window}))
                                {
                                    _ActiveForm = (Form)_ActiveControl;
                                    _ActiveForm.Activate();
                                    _ActiveForm.Focus();
                                    TextBox _tb = (TextBox)_ActiveForm.Controls.Find("txtMessage", true).FirstOrDefault();
                                    _tb.Select(_tb.Text.Length, 0);
                                }
                            }
                        }
```